# c++ : variadic template and function overloading

Tags: c++, variadic-functions, overload-resolution

see example below live : https://onlinegdb.com/Hkg6iQ3ZNI

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

class A 
{
    public:
    A(int v=-10):v_(v){}
    void print()
    {
        std::cout << "called A: " << v_ << std::endl;
    }
    private:
    int v_;
};

void f(int v)
{
    std::cout << "called f: " << v << std::endl;
    
}


template<typename T,typename ... Args>
void run(A&& a,
         T&& t,
         Args&& ... args)
{
    a.print();
    t(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}


template<typename T,typename ... Args>
void run(T&& t,
          Args&& ... args)
{
  run(A(),
      std::forward<T>(t),
      std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main()
{
    int v_function=1;
    int v_a = 2;
    
    run(f,v_function);
    
    return 0;
}
```

The code above compiles, runs and print (as expected):

> called A: -10
>
> called f: 1

but if the main function is modified to:

```
int main()
{
    int v_function=1;
    int v_a = 2;
    
    run(f,v_function);
    
    // !! added lines !!

    A a(v_a);
    run(a,f,v_function);
    
    return 0;
}
```

then compilation fails with error:

> main.cpp:30:6: error: no match for call to ‘(A) (void (&)(int), int&)’
>
> t(std::forward(args)...);
>
> ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

which seems to indicate that even when an instance of A is passed as first argument, the overload function

```
void(*)(T&&,Args&&...)
```

is called, and not

```
void(*)(A&&,T&&,Args&&...)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With

```
template<typename T,typename ... Args>
void run(A&& a,
         T&& t,
         Args&& ... args)
```

`a` is not a forwarding reference, but an rvalue reference.  That means when you do `run(a,f,v_function);` that function will not be selected because `a` is an lvalue and those can't be bound to rvalue references.  There are two quick ways to fix this.  First, use `std::move` on `a` like

```
run(std::move(a),f,v_function);
```

but this isn't great.  `a` isn't actually moved in the function so you are kind of violating the principle of least surprise.

The second option is to make `A` in the function a template type so it becomes a forwarding reference and then you can constrain it to be of type `A` like

```
template<typename A_, typename T,typename ... Args, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<A_>, A>, bool> = true>
void run(A_&& a,
         T&& t,
         Args&& ... args)
{
    a.print();
    t(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: certainly worth another question, or further reading on my side, but what is the "std::decay_t<A_>" for ?

Comment: @Vince It's a shortcut to remove the reference, const, and volatile qualification of the type.  It makes it much easier to check its type when you remove all of those permutations.

Comment: while the proposed solution works fine on onlinegdb.com, but on my laptop it does not compile saying the call of overload is ambiguous (when passing only the function to run), as if the enable with was not working. gcc is at version 7.4.0.

Comment: @Vince Could you share a link to a [mre]?

Comment: oh, the code of the question was an attempt to write a minimal reproducible experiment --; My original code is quite more complex.

Comment: the proposed solution, live : https://onlinegdb.com/r1zm52ZE8

Comment: @Vince Your code works just fine [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a5767a75a7cae896).  You have me confused when you said *when passing only the function to run* because you you pass a function plus a variable in your post so I didn't know if that was different code or code from your post.

Comment: indeed, sorry for the confusion. I meant "run(f,v_function);"

Comment: @Vince Okay.  Not sure what the issue is.  It works fine with GCC7.4 [here](https://godbolt.org/z/Gh-YPY).

Comment: thanks, I may have another issue. Will keep looking if I made an error somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Your code works, if you are calling `run` with an `rvalue`.

[Playable example here.](https://godbolt.org/z/KKwCeY)

As NathanOliver already sad: void `run(A&& a, T&& t, Args&& ... args)` expects an `rvalue reference`.

Basic idea of an `rvalue reference`: You are passing an `rvalue` to a function (e.g. a string literal). That value will be copied to the function. This work is unnecessary. Instead, you are just "moving" the reference to that value, so that it is "owned" by a different part of your program. [Move constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor) are a good starting point for understanding this problem.

Comment: While I do get the idea and why the code does work when passing an r-value, the part I do not get is how to create a run function that would accept indifferently r and l values

Comment: Hmmm. Good question... Well, the simplest answer to that would be pass-by-copy, but I guess that is not what you want.